# convert string representing a binary number to binary

Tags: serial, programming, c++

I have a serial input "1111111" and I would like to convert this to a binary B1111111 that I can send to a led matrix.

I tried to search, but, all the results were misleading, led to full text to binary conversion. Please advise.

edit:
This is my sample code where I am missing a step in the conversion part

```
LedControl mat = LedControl(DIN_PIN, CLK_PIN, CS_PIN, MAX_SEG); // MAX7219
void OneLine() {

//input
char text[] = "11111110";
//convert to binary number somehow


//show one line
      mat.setRow(0, 0, convertednr);
}
```

Comment: "I tried to search, but, all the results were misleading", How about start from understanding of [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)? An ASCII '1' that show on your Serial Monitor is binary 0x31, a binary value of 1 is ASCII '1' - '0' (0x31 - 0x30).

Comment: Have you searched for something like "C++ binary to int"? There is the `strtoi()` function, which also takes a parameter with the number base used (which is 2 for binary). Please try it

Comment: why do you need to convert to binary? ... what will you do with the binary number?

Comment: I receive this as serial input and would like to send it to a 8x8 led display row (max7219)

Comment: why do you need a binary number for that?

Comment: Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to add at least one example of what you tried.

Comment: @jsotola added sample code.

Comment: @chrisl: `strtoi()` is not standard. He should be using [`strtol()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html).

Comment: @EdgarBonet Thanks, this did the job and I don't need to further convert this do binary, the ledcontrol can work with this.

Comment: Is your edit meant as a solution? If so, remove it from the question and write a proper answer. You can mark it (later) as accepted, if it fits you best. This is the way this Q&A site works, it is not a forum. -- If it is not a solution, [edit] and explain why.

Comment: @thebusybee the solution was in EdgarBonet's comment: convert to integer, then I can pass this to the led matrix without further conversion.

Comment: @vilmarci As mentioned by the busybee, you shouldn't change your original post to make it right. This confused the future readers of this post and they can't see where is the problem. You should either post your working code as an Answer, or simply leave it "as is".

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @EdgarBonet, I can convert the string to binary number with `strtoul()` and pass this to my led control.
Adding this as an answer for future readers:

```
 LedControl mat = LedControl(DIN_PIN, CLK_PIN, CS_PIN, MAX_SEG); // MAX7219
void OneLine() {

//input
char text[] = "11111110";
//convert to number
uint32_t convertednr = strtoul(text, NULL, 2);
//print out
mySerial.println(convertednr);

//show one line
      mat.setRow(0, 0, convertednr);
```

Comment: you can use `mySerial.println(convertednr, BIN);`

Comment: Re “_I can convert the string to decimal number_”: Note that `strtoul()` converts the string to a **binary** (not _decimal_) number, and that is what you LED control is using (`convertednr` is a binary number). You may be confused by the fact that `mySerial.println(convertednr)` converts this binary number to a decimal string representation, for the purpose of displaying it on the serial port.

Comment: thanks @EdgarBonet, corrected the text